# Recursion in Prolog when calculating coordinates of koch curve

Tags: recursion, prolog

I have to calculate coordinates of a koch curve in Prolog and already got some nice and good
help [here](http://Prolog%20-%20Calculating%20coordinates%20of%20Koch-curve) which really made it easier to understand how to decompose the problem into smaller problems.
I tried to do that but didn't come that far. I must admit I'm really quarreling with recursions and don't come behind what I'm doing wrong.
I have to programm a koch-curve of Level N which should start at (Sx,Sy) and end at (Ex,Ey).

The advice I already got was to do the implementation in the following way:

```
generatelines(N, S, E, Segments) :-
segments(S, E, InitialSegments),
iterate_level(N, InitialSegments, Segments).
```

I started to do it like this:

```
segments(Ls1,Ls):-segments((Sx,Sy),(Ex,Ey),Ls).

segments((Sx,Sy),(Ex,Ey),Ls):-
X2 is Sx+(Ex-Sx)/3,
Y2 is Sy+(Ey-Sy)/3,
R1 is sqrt((X2-Sx)*(X2-Sx)+(Y2-Ey)*(Y2-Ey)),
Phi1 is atan((Y2-Sy)/(X2-Sx)),
X3 is X2 +R1*cos((Phi1-240)*pi/180),
Y3 is Y2 +R1*sin((Phi1+240)*pi/180),
X4 is X2+(X2-Sx),
Y4 is Y2+(Y2-Sy),
Ls=[
    [(Sx,Sy),(X2,Y2)],
    [(X2,Y2),(X3,Y3)],
    [(X3,Y3),(X4,Y4)],
    [(X4,Y4),(Ex,Ey)]
   ],    
next_level_segments(Ls).


next_level_segments(Ls):-next_level_segments(Ls,List). 

next_level_segments([[(Sx,Sy),(Ex,Ey)]|E],Ls):-
X2 is Sx+(Ex-Sx)/3,
Y2 is Sy+(Ey-Sy)/3,
R1 is sqrt((X2-Sx)*(X2-Sx)+(Y2-Ey)*(Y2-Ey)),
Phi1 is atan((Y2-Sy)/(X2-Sx)),
X3 is X2 +R1*cos((Phi1-240)*pi/180),
Y3 is Y2 +R1*sin((Phi1+240)*pi/180),
X4 is X2+(X2-Sx),
Y4 is Y2+(Y2-Sy),
append(Cs,[
    [(Sx,Sy),(X2,Y2)],
    [(X2,Y2),(X3,Y3)],
    [(X3,Y3),(X4,Y4)],
    [(X4,Y4),(Ex,Ey)],
    Ls ],
next_level_segments(E,Cs).

next_level_segments([],_):-!. 
append([],Ls,Ls).
append([X|As],Bs,[X|Cs]):- append(As,Bs,Cs).
```

When I'm trying to calculate `segments((60,0),(-60,0),X))` without 
the `next_level_segments` I get the right four coordinates between 
the start-point (60,0) and (-60,0):

```
[[ (60, 0), (20, 0)],
[ (20, 0), (0.0, -34.64)],
[ (0.0, -34.64), (-20, 0)], 
[ (-20, 0), (-60, 0)]]
```

With this pairs I would like to generate the next 4 coordinates between for example start point `(60,0)` and end point `(20,0)` using the auxiliary predicate `next_level_segment`.
When I look at the trace it seems that I'm (hopefully) not that wrong with my 
implementation, but I'm not able to get those next 16 new coordinates and
I guess the problem is the way I'm doing the recursion.

Maybe somebody may give me some advice what I'm doing wrong.
Thanks

Comment: In my answer to your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41419143/prolog-calculating-coordinates-of-koch-curve I suggested this decomposition into different predicates. But I noted that you should use "*several distinct predicates each with its own responsibilities*". You are not doing this. Only *one* predicate should contain all the numerical computations; only *one* (other) predicate should apply those computations to pairs of points; only *one* (other) predicate should iterate this computation over multiple levels.

Comment: Oh:-( okay, well I try to do it once again.  Thats been the try according to your advice, I guess I wasn't the best...No matter..I try again. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about your problem domain, but I definitely see a problem in your code:

```
next_level_segments(Ls) :- next_level_segments(Ls,List).
```

You probably get a singleton variable "warning" here (every singleton variable warning should be regarded as an indication of **a serious error** in Prolog!). So you're going along, evaluating `segments` when Prolog gets to this line. Let me remove some intervening lines to highlight the issue:

```
segments((Sx,Sy),(Ex,Ey),Ls):-
    Ls=[...],
    next_level_segments(Ls).
```

So, at this point, for Prolog to prove `segments/3`, all it has to do is see if `next_level_segments(Ls)` succeeds. Because `next_level_segments/1` essentially discards the binding of `List` (you could replace it with `_`), nothing happens here to propagate that information anywhere. This is probably the nut of your problem. You need to get the result of that and do something with it.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer! I followed your advice, but as far as I can see, unfortunately it doesn't make a change.

Comment: @claire please edit your question and append your changed code so I can take a look at it

Comment: Hi! I'll try it again, I guess I'll have to work over my implementation again. But thanks for your time!!